# Concatenating binary numbers

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to code a program that will take a floating point number in base 10 and convert its fractional part in base 2. In the following code, I am intending to call my converting function into a printf, and format the output; the issue I have lies in my fra_binary() where I can't figure out the best way to return an integer made of the result of the conversion at each turn respectively (concatenation).  Here is what I have done now (the code is not optimized because I am still working on it) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fra_binary(double fract) ;

int main() 
{
    long double n ;
    double fract, deci ;
    printf("base 10 :\n") ;
    scanf("%Lf", &n) ;
    fract = modf(n, &deci) ;
    int d = deci ;
    printf("base 2: %d.%d\n", d, fra_binary(fract)) ;

    return(0) ;
}

int fra_binary(double F) 
{
    double fl ;
    double decimal ;
    int array[30] ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
        fl = F * 2 ;
        F = modf(fl, &decimal) ;
        array[i] = decimal ;
        if (F == 0) break ;
    }

    return array[0] ;
}
```

Obviously this returns partly the desired output, because I would need the whole array concatenated as one int or char to display the series of 1 and 0s I need. So at each turn, I want to use the decimal part of the number I work on as the binary number to concatenate (1 + 0 = 10 and not 1). How would I go about it?
Hope this makes sense!

Comment: You have a very clear case of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by returning that array (or rather a pointer to its first element). Time to find a good book or tutorial, and read about *scope* and *life time* of variables.

Comment: Oh and if you declare a function to return one type, and then define it to return another, that won't work very well, and one source of warnings or errors from the compiler.

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude, but as I said in the original post, I left "return array" as an indication of my intention to use the concatenated result of my for loop. In my code, you'll see I have stored each repetition of the loop in the array, but what I am really trying to do is to concatenate each repetition to an int or to a char that I can use in my main(). Hope it's a bit clearer.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, you want to print the binary representation of a `double`, and the above is a mixture of C / pseudo-code to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Okay, probably best if I edit it to my previous output so it won't create confusion anymore. The point remains the same: in my attempt to convert the fractional part of the number, I can't manage to have an output I can use in my main function.

Comment: Yes, because the code won't compile anyway - the definition and declaration of `fra_binary` are different.

Comment: Edited... Sorry.

Comment: Can you show an example input and expected output?

Comment: Nope, it won't compile: please provide a tested [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. And shouldn't you be using `modfl` not `modf`, along with `long double fract, deci ;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return array[0] ;` is only the first value of `int array[30]` set in `fra_binary()`.  Code discards all but the first calculation of the loop `for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++)`.

> convert its fractional part in base 2

OP's loop idea is a good starting point.  Yet `int array[30]` is insufficient to encode the fractional portion of all `double` into a "binary".

> can't figure out the best way to return an integer

Returning an `int` will be insufficient.  Instead consider using a string - or manage an integer array in a likewise fashion.

Use defines from `<float.h>` to drive the buffer requirements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

char *fra_binary(char *dest, double x) {
  _Static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2, "Unexpected FP base");
  double deci;
  double fract = modf(x, &deci);
  fract = fabs(fract);
  char *s = dest;
  do {
    double d;
    fract = modf(fract * 2.0, &d);
    *s++ = "01"[(int) d];
  } while (fract);
  *s = '\0';

  // For debug
  printf("%*.*g --> %.0f and .", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 8, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x,
      deci);

  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  // Perhaps           53           - -1021       + 1
  char fraction_string[DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP + 1];
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, -0.0));
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, 1.0));
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, asin(-1)));  // machine pi
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, -0.1));
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, DBL_MAX));
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, DBL_MIN));
  puts(fra_binary(fraction_string, DBL_TRUE_MIN));
}
```

Output

```
                       -0 --> -0 and .0
                        1 --> 1 and .0
       3.1415926535897931 --> 3 and .001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011
     -0.10000000000000001 --> -0 and .0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
  1.7976931348623157e+308 --> 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and .0
  2.2250738585072014e-308 --> 0 and .00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
  4.9406564584124654e-324 --> 0 and .000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Also unclear why input is `long double`, yet processing is with `double`.  Recommend using just one FP type.

Comment: Your comments really helped me understand the problem I had. Nonetheless, I have decided to go another way completely and dropped the idea of handling the conversion in a separate function. Instead, I work on the data in the main() function and print the array with a for loop. Definitely less efficient, but convenient. Thank you for all the great explanations though!

Answer (score 0):

Note that your algorithm finds out the binary representation of the fraction most significant bit first.

One way to convert the fractional part to a binary string, would be to supply the function with a string and a string length, and have the function fill it with up to that many binary digits:

```
/* This function returns the number of chars needed in dst
   to describe the fractional part of value in binary,
   not including the trailing NUL ('\0').
   Returns zero in case of an error (non-finite value).
*/
size_t fractional_bits(char *dst, size_t len, double value)
{
    double  fraction, integral;
    size_t  i = 0;

    if (!isfinite(value))
        return 0;

    if (value > 0.0)
        fraction = modf(value, &integral);
    else
    if (value < 0.0)
        fraction = modf(-value, &integral);
    else {
        /* Zero fraction. */
        if (len > 1) {
            dst[0] = '0';
            dst[1] = '\0';
        } else
        if (len > 0)
            dst[0] = '\0';
        /* One binary digit was needed for exact representation. */
        return 1;            
    }

    while (fraction > 0.0) {
        fraction = fraction * 2.0;
        if (fraction >= 1.0) {
            fraction = fraction - 1.0;
            if (i < len)
                dst[i] = '1';
        } else
            if (i < len)
                dst[i] = '0';
        i++;
    }

    if (i < len)
        dst[i] = '\0';
    else
    if (len > 0)
        dst[len - 1] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

The above function works very much like [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), except it takes only the `double` whose fractional bits are to be stored as a string of binary digits (`0` or `1`). and returns `0` in case of an error (non-finite `double` value).

Another option is to use an unsigned integer type to hold the bits. For example, if your code is intended to work on architectures where `double` is an IEEE-754 Binary64 type or similar, the mantissa has up to 53 bits of precision, and an `uint64_t` would suffice.

Here is an example of that:

```
uint64_t  fractional_bits(const double  val, size_t  bits)
{
    double    fraction, integral;
    uint64_t  result = 0;

    if (bits < 1 || bits > 64) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!isfinite(val)) {
        errno = EDOM;
        return 0;
    }

    if (val > 0.0)
        fraction = modf(val, &integral);
    else
    if (val < 0.0)
        fraction = modf(-val, &integral);
    else {
        errno = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    while (bits-->0) {
        result = result << 1;
        fraction = fraction * 2.0;
        if (fraction >= 1.0) {
            fraction = fraction - 1.0;
            result = result + 1;
        }
    }

    errno = 0;
    return result;
}
```

The return value is the binary representation of the fractional part: [i]fractional_part[/i] ≈ [i]result[/i] / 2[sup][i]bits[/i][/sup], where [i]bits[/i] is between 1 and 64, inclusive.

In order for the caller to detect an error, the function clears `errno` to zero if no error occurred. If an error does occur, the function returns zero with `errno` set to `EDOM` if the value is not finite, or to `EINVAL` if `bits` is less than 1 or greater than 64.

You can combine the two approaches, if you implement an arbitrary-size unsigned integer type, or a bitmap type.